# Run function on load on .map element in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a set of components being rendered from a `.map()` function in my React application.

I have a function that fires on element's `onClick` which works great. However, I also need to fire this function automatically on a specific element when the page loads.

Here's a rather rudimentary example: https://codesandbox.io/s/ecstatic-cartwright-ve84yt.

So in the example, I have an array of 5 names, when you click the card, the field at the bottom displays the name of the selected card.
What I'm trying is to pre-select (Without using `setState`'s initial value) one of the cards.

Answer (score 1):

If the selectedName is not initialize, select first name in the list.

```
Selected Name: {this.state.selectedName || names[0]}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/little-hill-wv4200

Comment: It is also good advice on how to set the default value of your state. But I am not sure that it will work with remote data.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to preselect. You have to use componentDidMount lifecycle react method. It will be fired after your component will be rendered.

```
  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
      selectedName: names[1]
    });
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, I actually can't use `setState` so easily. All of the values in are dynamic, they run off a series of functions.

Comment: as a commenter above said you can set a default state, like this:
this.state = { selectedName: names[1] }; without setState

Comment: Sorry, I meant I can't set any initial value as all of the data that comes from the cards is dynamic and loaded in.

Comment: Do you have any marker for a specific element from the remote source you use?

Comment: Because I do not understand how you going to determine this specific element. The only way to do it in an array is by using indexes.